# How to test that a string field in a MongoDB document is not empty?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to get the number of documents that have a field with an empty string. This field, lets call it "Field_One" is present in all documents (so, to be clear, I am not trying to find if the field exists or not, I want to find which documents have nothing (empty string) in field "Field_One".

I tried using (using the C# driver):

```
collection.Find(Query.NE("Field_One", BsonNull.Value)).Count()
collection.Find(Query.NE("Field_One", BsonString.Null)).Count()
```

and even (someone suggested this somewhere):

```
collection.Find(Query.GT("Field_One", BsonString.Empty)).Count()
```

But it doesn't work (they return all the documents).

Also, as a related question: Is this the best way to get the number of matching documents in a collection? As far as I understand this, it wont actually retrieve the documents from the database to my program, so the count calculation is done in the MongoDB server.

Comment: yes count is done on the server. just as a sanity check, when you say empty string, does it show up as "" value when you fetch the document and examine that field?

Comment: Hello Asya, thanks for your reply. I fetched the JSON and it does show as "" for those documents that have no data in that field. So the field is there, of type String and has "" for some documents, and has information for others.

Comment: in mongo shell, you can try:  db.collection.find({field: { $type:10  }}). Check this documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/

Answer (score 12):

`BsonNull.Value` translates into null
`BsonString.Empty` translates into ""
`BsonObject.Create("")` translates into "" as well

```
 collection.Find(Query.NE("Field_One", BsonString.Empty)).Count()
```

translates into `"Field_One": { "$ne": "" }` what should be exactly what you are looking for if the field is actually filled with ""

Answer (score 7):

In order to test a string isn't empty, in Javascript it is simply :

```
collection.find({Field_One:{ $ne: "" }})
```

see [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/).
I can't help you translating that into C# driver language.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are querying for documents of a class looking something like:

```
public class MyClass {
        public string Field_One { get; set; }
        //... other attributes, constructors, methods etc...
}
```

You can also write your query using expression lambdas like this for example:

```
var res = collection.Find(Query<MyClass>.NE(m => m.Field_One, BsonString.Empty)).Count();
```